# Get encoded content embedded in html page

Tags: html, encoding

I'm writing in order to ask for some help or advice regarding my problem. The trouble i'm facing is the following:
Exploiting a path traversal on a local testing machine, i was able to get a bunch of log files (by which i mean, they are present, and could be downloaded) but... Here's the only way i can get it

```
<div class="col-1-1">
 ...
 X509KEY���>$�?��?�(?d�8�21�s����i�5
 ...
</div>
```

I already tried modifying my request to "Accept-Charset: UTF-8", also tried to capture it with Burp after which i saved the ".gz" file as [name].gz but that didn't work out either. Lately I've been messing around with wget (in python) to see if i can save only the content of the file (in it's natural encoded format) and deny the rest of the html content, but I doubt it'd work either.

Thank you for any advice in advance:
R.

Comment: Is your question "_How do I get the content of a file with wget in python?_"? Also, please format your text properly, you may use the code block button

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your notification, i'll format it right away. As for the question: Nope, i just wrote it to say that i'm trying that at the moment (take it as a list of "things i tried so far" :) ) What I'm curious about is that how would you guys/gals approach such a matter if you were facing it? Cheers: R.

Comment: Thank you for re-formatting and clarifying your question. You mentioned this is a log file, do you know which program generates this log file? that would shed on some light as to why only part of the file is scrambled

Comment: Sure, here's what I know of the Server:
OS: IBM AIX 7.4.1
Web Server: WebSphere Application Server
WebServ. Version: ?
The log was generated by the server and zipped by "wassrvr" user (i guess that is the web master's account for the webserver), the extension is .gz

Comment: If you want to post a large portion of text feel free to edit your original question. If you want to add the full log file please post it on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and edit your question with a link to it

Comment: I doubt I'd have permission to provide the complete log file as the server used to be a live-, internet facing server a couple of days earlier. The real question is that the files in question are Access-,Error- and SystemOut.logs and what i'm interested in would be the following: 
Does it contain any records of anyone accessing it? Does it contain any user credentials? If so, we'd have to alert approximately 200+ users to change their passwords.And as far as i know, this server was mainly functioning as a financial hub for creating contracts and God knows for how long this Vuln was present...

Comment: I see, the way I would approach your situation is to determine what **type** of logs I can get access to and act based on that. The bottom line is that you do not have to demonstrate How to take advantage of a vulnerability, only that the vuln exists, someone else may take advantage of it in ways you havent thought of

Comment: I got to a point where i believe you are correct. Even if i weren't able to get anything concrete, someone else might have been. As for the accessible log: All of them... they kept a pretty neat record of where and under what names did they archive the daily logs (which could have been read by anyone from the sysadmin's .bash_history... Example:
absolute/path/to/access_log_2017-02-19.gz
absolute/path/to/access_log_2017-02-20.gz
absolute/path/to/access_log_2017-02-21.gz
absolute/path/to/error_log_2017-02-21.gz
etc...
i really am happy that this server got taken down. :D